# how to prefix the input using inquirer.prompt

Tags: node.js, process, prompt, readline

Given the following...

```
var prompts = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'message',
    default: 'Some Message'
    message: 'Commit message?',
}]
require('inquirer').prompt(prompts, function(){})
```

the terminal will output the following

```
[?] Commit message? (Some Message) ||
```

The "||" symbolizes my cursor

If I press ENTER, without typing anything, inquirer will use (Some Message) as the default input value.

However, if I type anything at all "Some Message gets overwritten"

I would like to do the following instead

```
[?] Commit message? || Some Message
```

The "||" symbolizes my cursor

Basically I would like to modify the default message, or prefix the input value, allowing me to modify the prefix.

My best solution... which does not work is the following

```
var prompts = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'message',
    message: 'Commit message?',
    when: function(){
        process.nextTick(function(){
           process.stdout.write('Some Message');
        });
    }
}]
require('inquirer').prompt(prompts, function(){})
```

This will do the following

```
[?] Commit message? Some Message ||
```

The "||" symbolizes my cursor

This seems like it would work, but I am unable to move my cursor backward in order to modify the message.

Is it possible to print a modifiable string to the terminal?

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to do that:

```
var Inquirer = require("inquirer");

var chalk = require("chalk");


Inquirer.prompt([
  {
    type: "input",
    message: "Commit message? " + chalk.cyan( "Some Message" ),
    name: "message",
    filter: function(val) {
      return val + " Some Message";
    }
  }
], function( answers ) {
  console.log( JSON.stringify(answers, null, "  ") );
});
```

You can also make your own prompts.

Cheers.

Comment: This does not answer the question properly. The OP wants to modify the `user input` in the prompt.